# Image List view with text and URL

Tags: javascript, listview

I want to display and list with icon and text. List is link to specific URL. I am storing all these in a array but image is not populating from the array. here is a spinet.

```
var mainPanel = [ {
    icon : "images/green/home.png",
    title : "Home",
    url : "#tilehome-page"
}, {
    icon : "images/green/home.png",
    title : "Mayor's Conner)",
    url : "#mayorsmessage-page"
}, {
    icon : "images/green/home.png",
    title : "Report A Problem",
    url : "#reportaproblem-page"
} ];  

function createmenuPnl() {
    var items = '';
    //ul = $(".mainMenu:empty"); 
    var ulStr = "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < mainPanel.length; i++) {
        items += '<li><a href="' + mainPanel[i].url + '"> + mainPanel[i].title
        + '</a></li>';
    }
    ulStr+= items;
    ulStr+='</ul>';
    console.log('The ulStr formed is:'+ulStr);
    $("#cssmenu").append(ulStr);
    $("#cssmenu").trigger( "updatelayout" ); 

}
```

All I want is to add image icon dynamically in the list

Comment: **[Check here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ynfrkzwg/)**

Comment: Hey I already achieve this. How to add icon before text in the list.

Comment: You can append `i` tag before your text..

Comment: Thanks Got it. I was doing a syntactical error.

Answer (score 0):

you forget single quote just before mainPanel[i].title.. it should be like this..

`items += '<li><a href="' + mainPanel[i].url + '">' + mainPanel[i].title
        + '</a></li>';`

Comment: yaa thats ture by mistake i forgot to place the single quote here but in my orignal code is fine. How can add an icon which is listed in the array in this list with text.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < mainPanel.length; i++) {
  items += '<li><a href="' + mainPanel[i].url + '"><img src="' + mainPanel[i].icon '"/>'  + mainPanel[i].title
  + '</a></li>';
 }

Comment: again you made a mistake.. you forgot + after mainPanel[i].icon... try this..[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akki199421/3rjy34pa/)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go
The problem is in your loop for

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainPanel.length; i++) {
    // after '"> need one '
    items += '<li><a href="' + mainPanel[i].url + '">' + mainPanel[i].title
    + '</a></li>';
}
```